# New monitor: what are these artifacts or distortion?

Tags: display, hardware-failure

I bought the Dell S2417DG which includes GSYNC, and I am getting some horrible artifacts (maybe more often with darker colors). It appears to occur in any resolution. My other Acer monitors on the same PC do not have this issue. The monitor is plugged into my RTX 2070 with a DisplayPort cable. Seems to happen anywhere: Netflix HBO Max, JPEGs, etc. Taken with a camera:

- [New Dell monitor](https://i.imgur.com/nJTxdhc.jpg)
- [Normal older monitor](https://i.imgur.com/XQiM4Q6.jpg)

How can I fix this?

NVIDIA settings for the monitor:
[image]

More comparisons in high-res:

- [Look at the hair. New Dell monitor](https://lensdump.com/i/jUk34m)
- [Look at the hair. Normal older monitor](https://lensdump.com/i/jUksrP)

This is the same PC hooked up at the same time.

Things I have tried that did not help:

- Trying a different cable
- Trying a different port on the GPU
- Resetting the monitor to factor settings

Comment: It looks like you are playing a movie.  Is that the only time this happens?

Comment: @Keltari No, I see artifacts on still pictures too.

Comment: I doubt its the monitor.  More than likely its a configuration/setting of the video card and the monitor.  However, it wouldnt hurt to test the monitor on another graphics card.

Comment: Do you have the latest nvidia drivers? Did you try updating the drivers for the monitor as well?

Comment: @hextech I have upgraded my GPU drivers and monitor drivers, same issue remains.

Comment: Can you confirm it's not the cable? And can you test the new dell monitor on another computer?

Comment: @hextech I have already tried different cables. I don't have another PC to test with, but other monitors work just fine on this PC.

Comment: What you are seeing are compression artefacts. This is due to the way our video/image compression works and has nothing to do with your monitor. You are seeing them mostly in dark parts, where these artefacts usually stay hidden because they just arent bright enough. However in your case, the new monitor is configured to be brighter than your others. Way too bright! This can be due to settings in your nvidia control panel, settings on the monitor itself or settings in your video playback software. You can try to enable 'Use nvidia settings' for the new monitor and play with the Gamma option.

Comment: Few additional tests you may want to try. 1) Start the computer with another os (such as a fresh install of Linux on a USB). 2) Test the monitor with some nvidia testing program/ demo. 3) Test the monitor with another computer, ask to a friend, neighbour...  Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like your graphics card or your monitor applies some gamma correction to the display output, heavily brightening the dark parts in the process, which makes compression artifacts and color banding much more visible. Some monitors have a feature, often called "Black Equalizer", which does something similar.
I would reset your monitor settings first, if the issue is still there I would look in the Nvidia Control Panel for something that could cause this, and then also check the individual monitor settings.

Comment: There is no such setting on the monitor, or anything similar. What I am looking for on Nvidia Control Panel?

Comment: @Zeno I don't own an Nvidia desktop GPU myself, but you should be able to find the setting under Display -> Adjust Desktop Color Settings. But if you haven't messed with those settings before they should still be on default, where they normally should be. There's also a feature in Nvidia Freestyle, called "HDR Toning", which could also produce such artifacts by brightening dark parts on the display.
It might be helpful to do look at some test images from [here](https://www.eizo.be/monitor-test/), especially "Gradients" and "Gamma", to understand what's going on.

Comment: Also, have you tested if those artifacts get baked into screenshots?

Comment: Everything looks fine under Adjust desktop color settings. The settings are literally the same for all 3 monitors.

Comment: I uploaded an image of the NVIDIA Control Panel settings to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the 'artefacts' are present on both screens in the same place...just that the new monitor colour / brightness / contrast levels are emphasising it.  Have you tried something really high definition like a blu ray or 2k youtube video to see if it still shows?  Could be an overheating graphics card if it's completely random?

Perhaps check that all your cables are up to the latest spec?  HDMI cables are not all alike.  Maybe swap to display-port if available?